# Wordpress keeps on updating even after disabling auto update

Tags: wordpress

I want to disable all updates in my website. I have set below variable in `wp-config.php` file.

```
define( 'automatic_updater_disabled', true );

define( 'wp_auto_update_core', false );
```

But I don't know why, every other day it keeps on updating itself, which breaks some of my code.

Does any one know how to disable the updates PERMANENTLY !

Comment: it's related to theme update or plugin update ?

Comment: Try this one for plugin and theme "add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );" and "add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );"

Comment: @Dhruv both. I want to disable both.

Comment: Arif I have send you a answer please check and also visit the link i think you having a issue because you have write in small cap.and it's need to in UPPER case.

Comment: I think you define in lowercase instead of the uppercase case that's why you facing the issue

Answer (score 1):

By default, WordPress can automatically update itself when a security or minor release is available. 
For major releases, you have to initiate the update yourself. You also have to install plugin and theme updates yourself.

Wondering if you are on Managed Wordpress hosting??
IF YES then that's where those updates are happening automatically.
You can Hosting support to not update without confirming with you.

Answer (score 0):

> define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
>
> define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );

**Disable automatic WordPress plugin updates:**

> add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );

**Disable automatic WordPress theme updates:**

> add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );

For your better understanding please visit **[here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/configuring-automatic-background-updates/)**

Comment: You might want to edit this post to explicitly say **PHP constants are case-sensitive**, since OP seems to have missed this.

Answer (score 0):

On some hosting platforms you install Wordpress as an 'App' through something like *Installatron*. This has settings about updating Wordpress too, you may want to check for this in your hosting backend/dashboard.

It looks like this

[image: Installatron]

Where it says *My blog* it will probably say *Wordpress*. If you click edit below, it has some settings about updating.