# Major Wordpress update even with define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some sites were I got the last Major wordpress core update (WP 6) even with this line "define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );" in the wp-config.php.
Has anyone any ideas how this happened? (like is there a server configuration that can overrite that .. I don't think there could be but I have no clue how this happened). I know they can push through minor security updates, but a major one like this seems odd.

Comment: Hi @rcc_daniel!
Check those solutions  may someone helps you, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58955922/wordpress-keeps-on-updating-even-after-disabling-auto-update)

Comment: Thank you. Sry didn't see that this is essentially a duplicate question. I will check those solutions.